# Does "boiling milk" always mean pasteurization, especially in Mongolia?

Tags: food-safety, milk, asian-cuisine, language

The Lonely Planet guide for Mongolia uses "boiling milk" and pasteurization interchangeably:

> TB is a bacterial infection usually transmitted from person by
>   coughing, but which may be transmitted through consumption of
>   **unpasteurised milk**.
>
> Milk that has been **boiled** is safe to drink, and the souring of milk to
>   make yoghurt or cheese also kills the bacilli.

The Wikipedia article on pasteurization mentions various time periods and temperatures as qualifying as pasteurization.

But I don't know what the term "boiling milk" means. In particular, I don't know whether "boiling milk" always means pasteurization. Is there a time and duration that'd qualify as boiling milk, but wouldn't count as pasteurization?

Failing that, in Mongolia, does "boiling milk" always equate to a time and temperature that'd achieve pasteurization?

Comment: Can someone with 300 rep replace "asian-cuisine" with "mongolian-cuisine" please?

Comment: I am not even sure that this is somehow related to Mongolian language or Mongolian cuisine. Boiled milk is boiled milk everywhere. It's also unlikely that the Lonely Planet writer was a Mongolian, or that he used the English word "boil" in some strange Mongolian sense.

Answer (score 1):

Most milk is pasteurised by bringing it to between 71 and 74C for 15 to 30 seconds. This is called High Temperature Short Time pasteurisation.

Boiling milk means just that: bringing the milk to its boiling point, which is 100C. That should naturally should make it as safe as the HTST pasteurised variety as it will spend plenty of time at well over the highest temperature reached in that process.